# How to load in Javascript content in Selenium-Automated Firefox Web Browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I've recently been trying to scrape a dynamicaly loaded chart on this website. But to scrape it I also need it to load in. Which it does not when using an automated Firefox browser with Selenium. When logged in to this website, the chart may be dispalyed as such -->

[image: Regular Browser Web Page]

But when I use the following script, it hits me with this instead:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

fp = '/Users/marcojohanssontornblom/Desktop/FireFoxyProfile'

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.set_preference('profile', fp)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.get('https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/IP/IV/')
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

[image: Automated Web Page]

For the record I've, as shown in the code-block above, tried resolving the problem by adding a Firefox Profile and several arguments, but they've not produced any other results. I've found that it is of importance that I use the Firefox browser for scraping purposes, but even so trying to use the chrome webdriver wouldn't work when I tried it.

~ A felow scraper